Why does my material disappear when I rotate it?
I am new to Blender and I can't fix this problem for some reason. The 'L' letter won't show no matter how much lighting I put but when I rotate it, the letter appears. Is there any way to fix this?



The letter 'L' only shows if i rotate it to the angle of the right earpiece but if I do that, the letter 'R' of the right earpiece disappears. It's like the letter will show only at a specific placement.


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

yes, I have already edited my post, sorry I am new to all this stuff.

You need to pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save again and share   ;)

ok, I have done that

@moonboots Not necessary for the solution, but a good practice.

The problem is that you have plugged the Fac (a greyscale/float value) output of the Magic Texture node into the Normal input of the Bump node. You have to plug it into the Height input. It just works coincidentally without error on one side. And I think you can reduce the Strength value. By the way, the "L" is flipped. Select the face in the UV Editor then scale on X by -1.


yes! It worked, thank you so much!!!
